# Using cordova-plugin-googleplus and Ionic 2 for google login does not allow pick YouTube Channel

Tags: cordova, youtube-api, ionic2, google-plus-signin

So inappbrowser google login will be disable in April 20, 2017. So I have to switch to cordova-plugin-googleplus. But the problem of cordova-plugin-googleplus is, in Android, when I login with a gmail account associated with multiple YouTube Channel, I can not pick the YouTube channel I want to get data from with the scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

When I connect with my Gmail account with my app, it will not show the "pick your YT channel" screen like in Web browser or iOs. How do I support to use google login and get the correct user YouTube channel info now if user has multiple YouTube channels with Ionic 2 app?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use other scope like the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube that use to manage your YouTube account. You can verfiy in this [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#identify-access-scopes) the purpose of different scope.

If you still get the same error, then try to check this [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/implementing-google-plus-sign-in-with-oauth-2-0-in-ionic-2/) if it can help you. This tutorial will help you on how to implement Google Plus Sign-In with OAuth 2.0 using Ionic 2. Just follow the step by step guide here on how to do it. It also, provide screenshot for you to follow it easily and sample code that you can copy.

For more information, check this [github](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) and another [tutorial](https://creatorup.com/build-mobile-app-for-your-youtube-channel-with-ionic2-and-angular2/).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I also experienced this, I tried it today and still did not work according to the question, can anyone help or have the same experience and have succeeded?